# There exist meager subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ whose complements have Lebesgue measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Probem 27 of Chapter 5 in Folland's Real Analysis.
I have been asked to solve this using generalized Cantor sets. Something related to the construction outlined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Post the question.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 1):

A "generalized" or "fat" Cantor set is constructed by removing open intervals from $[0,1]$ in such a way that the total removed length is less than $1$. The result is a nowhere-dense $C \subset [0,1]$ (since, anywhere you look, there's a missing interval) with positive Lebesgue measure. It's fairly quick to verify that removing the middle fourths at each step leaves behind something of measure $\mu(C) = 1/2$.

Can you fill up all the measure in the unit interval by taking a clever union of fat Cantor sets?

There's also a clean solution here (they don't talk about Cantor sets, though) https://mathoverflow.net/a/43480

Comment: *OR* you could just take a family $(C_n)_n$ of fat cantor sets with $\lambda(C_n)>1-1/n$, and there is no need to be clever. Heck, you could take $(C_n)_n$ to be a fat Cantor sets such that $\lambda([-n,n]\setminus C_n)<1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite example is the following. Given a real $r$, let $Seq(r)$ be the infinite binary sequence gotten from looking at the binary expansion of $r$ after the decimal point (in case $r$ has two binary expansions, pick the mostly-zeroes one). Then the set $Rand$ of $r$ such that "$1$" appears in $Seq(r)$ half the time - that is, the lim sup of (proportion of first $n$ bits of $Seq(r)$ which are "$1$"s) and the lim inf of the same are each equal to ${1\over 2}$ - is almost all of $\mathbb{R}$: its complement has measure zero.

Meanwhile, the set $Gen$ of reals $r$ such that the liminf and limsup defined above are $0$ and $1$, respectively - that is, $r$ has "long" strings of $0$s and "long" strings of $1$s - is comeager.

But $Gen\subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus Rand$.

("Gen" and "Rand" stand for "Generic" and "Random," which are technical terms in mathematical logic corresponding to category and measure, respectively.)